Azure Search: different index per user
I need to make a system for "chat with your documents" (In a frontend app, where each user has collections of documents).
Initially, we thought of manually chunking and embedding each collection of user documents into a separate QDRANT collection and then querying it when the user wants to chat with this document collection. But if we can get Azure AI Search to work, it could be better.
The issue is that I didn't find a way to have a separate vector set for each user, so that by (user_id, collection_id) we could query vectors that belong only to a specific (user, collection) pair.
Is this possible in Azure AI Search?

It should be possible to add metadata to your documents and use them as a means to filter it by specific user. The key here is to set the meta data columns properly when indexing and storing data in Azure AI Search. Refer here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-security-trimming-for-azure-search

